# Where do I find all Apple Guides for objective-c and cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I find that the xcode-builtin-documentation reader is hard to use. I want to see the root of all Guides available, to get an idea of how long I will have to keep reading until I can start. All the time some new Guide pops up to me, and I am wondering how many they are.

Is there an overview somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Start with http://developer.apple.com/mac - there are lots of docs there.

Answer (score 1):

The whole documentation can be browsed online on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).

Leopard Reference
http://developer.apple.com/reference/

Leopard Guides
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/

Almost always the search gives quite accurate results, so use either google

> NSString site:developer.apple.com

or use the search field on the page.

Additionally one should say, that if you right click on an article in the Xcode help, it offers you to open the document in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For Cocoa, your starting point is [Getting started with Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Cocoa/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001088). For Objective-C, your starting point is [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html). In each of these documents you will find links to other documents.

The root of Mac OS X API is [Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/). From this point you have access to all other documents.